# read xml on url by curl in magento 2

Tags: php, xml, magento, curl, magento2

as title, i want to read to parse xml on url by using curl in magento 2. but it not worked.
here is my code.

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$curl = $om->get('Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\Curl');
$curl->setConfig([
    'timeout'   => 5
];
$curl->write(\Zend_Http_Client::GET,$link);
$data = $curl->read();

if ($data === false) {          
    return false;
}
$data = preg_split('/^\r?$/m', $data, 2);
$data = trim($data[1]);
$curl->close();
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "doesn't work"? What are you observing? Any errors?

Comment: Thank for answering. it return null. and I replaced it by using php curl. and it worked. I dont know why it return null when i use curl of magento

Comment: Glad it worked for you...  Can you please update the question or ask a new one with your findings, perhaps someone can tell why one works and not the other.

Comment: Might you forgot to close braces (i.e. ");") for setConfig method.